# Can I cook lentils in a rice cooker?

Tags: rice-cooker, lentils

Can I cook lentils in a rice cooker? Would I need to adjust my lentils/water ratio?

Comment: wold you cook rice and lentils together? or rice is cooked yet? are lentils dry, fresh or canned yet cooked?

Comment: See:  http://www.seriouseats.com/talk/2011/01/whos-cooked-lentils-in-a-rice-cooker.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost certainly: [lots of recipes online](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rice%20cookler%22%20lentils&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a).

I'd go with the 'porridge' or 'brown rice setting' if your cooker has it.
Concensus on water ratio seems to be about same as for rice.

Here's a question which lists [More things you can cook in a rice cooker](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/20800/quinoa-in-a-rice-cooker/20801#20801).

With a quality cooker, you can also make baked beans and tasty onion soup.